# how can i bring what does not have a table, multi table

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, sql-server-2008

I have a problem with SQL, I want to do it in relation 4 tables (user, appuserFunctionRelation, organizations, GroupCommerce) where organizations is related to GroupCommerce and appuserFunctionRelation is related to both and to the other has the user id.

What I want to do is bring the GroupCommerce that the user does not have. How can I do that?

```
SELECT  
    [AppUserFunctionsRelation].[user],
    [CommerceGroup].Organization,
    [CommerceGroup].ID AS CommerceGroupID ,
    [CommerceGroup].Description AS CommerceGroupDescription
FROM  [AppUserFunctionsRelation] 
RIGHT JOIN [CommerceGroup]  
    ON   CommerceGroup.Organization = AppUserFunctionsRelation.Organization 
    AND  AppUserFunctionsRelation.[GroupCommerce] = [CommerceGroup].ID
 WHERE  AppUserFunctionsRelation.GroupCommerce IS NULL  
    AND CommerceGroup.Organization IN ( SELECT Organizations.[ID] 
                                        FROM AppUserFunctionsRelation 
                                        INNER JOIN Organizations 
               ON Organizations.ID = AppUserFunctionsRelation.Organization
               WHERE AppUserFunctionsRelation.[User] =22
     )
```

Tables:

```
User
ID|Description
1 |admin

Organization
ID|Description
1 |TestOrg
2 |TestOrg2

CommerceGroup
ID|Organization|Description
1 |1             |TestGC
2 |1             |TestGC2
3 |1             |TestGC3
4 |2             |TestGC4

AppUserFunctionsRelation
User|organization|CommerceGroup 
1   |1           |1
```

Expected result

```
user|organization|commercegroup
1   | 1          |2
1   | 1          |3
```

in case you have all the business groups of the organization it would be something like this

```
AppUserFunctionsRelation
User|organization|CommerceGroup 
1   |1           |0
```

---

It's a bit overdone but I need it to be like that,
with the 0 I realize that the user has all the trade groups of the organization 
id 1

I want to bring the trade groups that the user of that organization does not have associated with

Thank you

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results.

Comment: Your desired output is inconsistent with your sample data. Looks like user 1 has a relation to organization 1 which has a relation to all commerce groups except 4. Can you either fix you desired output or explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: Huh??? That makes no sense to me at all. There is something missing in your sample. But if you are posting details you should post them in the question as the comments are terrible for formatting.

Comment: sorry I'm new to stackoverFlow, there I will edit it, I hope you can help me thanks

Comment: Not a problem that you are new around here. But this just isn't at all clear. What is a trade group? The more I read your question the more confused I get.

Comment: Surely not, the organization can have many groups of businesses associated with it, so an organization can have many trade groups.
What I need is to bring all the groups of businesses that the user of a specific organization does not have

Comment: You keep interchanging the names which is incredibly confusing. trade group, business group and commerce group, I guess those are the same thing? But I think I finally see what you need. Have you looked at a left join? And of course your example query is using User 22 which is nowhere in your sample data.

Comment: Sorry my English is bad, I speak Spanish
if there is only groupcommerce
if the problem is that when I do the query brings all the groupcommerce that does not have an associated groupcommerce of another organization also brings it to me, there is the problem, I need to bring groupcommerce that does not have the user associated with a specific organization. I hope I have been clear, thank you

Comment: the example just put together, actually the user table has more row

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you want something like this. I made a number of assumptions about column names. If you really have the name ID in every table I would urge you to fix this. An OrganizationID is not suddenly just an ID because it is in the Organization table. Yes it is somewhat redundant but columns changing names across tables is challenging to work with.

This should work as I understand the question.

```
select *
from Users u
join Organization o on o.OrganizationID = u.UserID
join AppUserFunctionsRelation r on r.UserID = u.UserID and r.OrganizationID = o.OrganizationID
left join CommerceGroup cg on cg.OrganizationID = r.OrganizationID
where u.UserID = 1
    and cg.OrganizationID is null
```

--EDIT--

I supposed you could do something like this to remove the Users table. The results should be pretty much the same but this seems kind of useless now because all you get about a user is a number. Hard to identify the people like that.

```
select *
from Organization o
join AppUserFunctionsRelation r on r.OrganizationID = o.OrganizationID
left join CommerceGroup cg on cg.OrganizationID = r.OrganizationID
where cg.OrganizationID is null
```

Comment: it would not be working
look like this
select *
from AppUserFunctionsRelation r
join Organizations or on r.Organization = o.ID
join CommerceGroup cg on cg.Organization = r.Organization
where r. [User] = 37

I bring the CommerceGroup that the user has associated with, what I need is to bring the GC that does not have an associate on a specific organization

Comment: That is why there is a left join and where predicate to get only those that don't have a match.

Comment: in this case the relationship with user I do not need it, I just need the id of the user that is in the table AppUserFunctionsRelation
How would you get the users table?

Comment: What do you mean "how would you get the users table"?

Comment: how would the query be without the users table, that is what I meant

Comment: sorry with my english

Comment: Why do you need to remove the Users table? I suppose you could just start with Orgnization.

Comment: because I do not need the data of the user table, only its a I need user id

Comment: select *
from  Organizations
join AppUserFunctionsRelation r on r.Organization = Organizations.ID
left join CommerceGroup cg on cg.Organization = r.Organization and cg.ID = r.GroupCommerce
where r.[User] = 1
    and cg.Organization is null

Comment: What does "not work for me mean"? I understand that english is not your first language but the issue here is not a language barrier. It is the inability of you to understand that others can't read your mind here. I give up. I am the only person who has been trying to help and this question is a trainwreck. I would suggest you delete this question and try again. Here is a great place to start for your new question. https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: that the query I put up does not work for me, and it's similar to what you did,
Thanks for taking the time, trying to help me

Comment: Again...you have to explain "does not work for me". That is like taking your car to the shop and saying "it doesn't work, here are the keys". You would tell them what is wrong, not just a blanket, "it doesn't work". Your question is probably quite simple but you have not explained it clearly enough for others to help. Delete this question, clarify your request and post a new question with details.

Answer (score -1):

It would not be working

```
select *
from AppUserFunctionsRelation r
join Organizations or on r.Organization = o.ID
join CommerceGroup cg on cg.Organization = r.Organization
where r. [User] = 37
```

I bring the CommerceGroup that the user has associated with, what I need is to bring the GC that does not have an associate on a specific organization